# Magento redirect to same page

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I want to redirect user after submission of the following form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $custmlogin->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
```

to the same page. But after submit it take me to the homepage.

Any way to redirect it to same page after submit?

Answer (score 2):

Try using $this->_redirectReferer(); inside the module/controller/action where you process the form.

Answer (score 0):

Find where that form is processed in your module and change the : $this->redirect(/*/*) that will have to your link.